# A report for monthly newsletter subscription rates? (need advice)

Tags: groups

I've been trying to think of a way to create a report to see the total number of subscribers to our newsletter on a monthly basis.

Any ideas? I've hit the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide details on how you are doing these mailings, so I assume you are using the CiviCRM CiviMail function....  Just go to Reports | Mail Summary Report.

It does a nice job of listing, for each mailing (which in your case I would assume is monthly), the number of intended recipients (ie Subscribers), as well as Delivered, Bounced, and Opened.  You can add other related metrics to the detail, and filter to the mailings you are interested in.

Comment: Oh never mind- I see what you're saying. Yes, that would do it...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Views you might be able to use Aggregation on a field that has the 'month' and then 'count' the subscribers for that 'month' field. Aggregation is in the Advanced section of the View.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your subscribers are part of a group in CiviCRM? And are you creating a CiviCRM report or using Drupal Views? I assume you are creating a CiviCRM report? Then I would look at the Constituent Summary report?
And are you creating a report in the UI or adding a template in an extension using PHP?